# "Under sail" - literally only sail boats or also valid for boats with engines

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I wonder if the expression "under sail" can or should only be used in reference to boats that sail with the wind (i.e. have a sail) or if it could be used for boats and ships as well that move with engine power.

- How would a layman imagine a boat or ship if I'd tell him "We are under sail, heading towards ..."?
- How would a seaman understand it? Is it commonly used to indicate that the ship is moving or that it has a physical sail up?

Comment: Under sail is even said for things other than transport e.g. someone starting a project may say "we're under sail" . It has become a metaphor for starting  anything.

Comment: I was going to suggest *underway,* but this has already been addressed by cobaltduck in his answer below. When referring to boats or ships, *under sail* means moving by wind power *only*. Stockfisch is not asking about metaphorical uses.

Comment: Yes and this seems to be confused by degree.
Would even the most pedantic mariner have a problem with a steamship ‘sailing at dawn’ or ‘sailing for Brobdignagia’ or ‘sailing short handed’?
‘Under sail’ seems more clearly literal, which might merely be because using two words instead of just the one forces us to think more carefully about what we’re actually saying…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an avid boater, I can tell you the correct expression that encompasses both sail and power vessels is under *way.*  The [M-W Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under%20way) even gives it as the first definition:

> in motion :  not at anchor or aground

Though I would add that a vessel moored to a dock or pier is also not under way.

Meanwhile, the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/under-sail) indicates clearly that *under sail* means:

> If you cross the sea under sail, you cross it in a ship that has sails rather than an engine.

Note that technically, a vessel adrift and not under command is also under way.  To be more specific, if the engine is propelling the vessel, we say *under way and making way.*

Here's another reference, [Skysail Training](http://www.skysailtraining.co.uk/underway_making_way.htm), where we read that:

> Underway: not anchored, or made fast to the shore, or aground. (As defined in Colregs).
>
> Making way: being propelled through the water by sail, machinery, or oar.  (Not defined in Colregs)

Comment: Great to hear from someone with nautical experience, just the answer I was looking for!